# What are some good resources for learning PowerShell scripting?

Tags: scripting, powershell, resources

Are there online resources or books that you would recommend as an introduction to PowerShell scripting?  The resources I've found primarily focus on interactive use.

Comment: Questions relating to professional education are off topic per the [revised FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 7):

Book-wise, I recommend both [Windows PowerShell in Action](http://www.manning.com/payette/) by Bruce Payette and [Windows PowerShell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528492/) Cookbook by Lee Holmes. Payette's book is more of a deep dive into how PowerShell works, and the "Cookbook" is all about solving specific problems.

Answer (score 6):

I found this site:

http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/

which seems to have some good information (via the links on the right sidebar).

Comment: I found this site horrible to navigate.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to say the [PowerShell Guy](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/). Cannot go wrong with a MVP.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at a couple of the free e-books available as well, such as the two listed below. 
[Effective Windows Powershell](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6930.entry) and [The eBooklet Series: An Introduction to Microsoft PowerShell](http://nexus.realtimepublishers.com/ebmps.php)

Answer (score 3):

I liked these two books:

- [Windows PowerShell in Action](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932394907) by Bruce Payette
- [Windows PowerShell Pocket Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596521782) by Lee Holmes

Also, check out these sites:

- [MS Script Center](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/default.mspx)
- [Scripting with Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/hubs/msh.mspx)
- [The PowerShell blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/)
- [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following eBooks and eBooklets:

- [Mastering PowerShell](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/), a
  20-chapter eBook by Dr. Tobias
  Weltner (PowerShell MVP). This is an
  English version of [Scripting mit
  Windows PowerShell - Der
  Einsteiger-Workshop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3866456204) (656 pages)
- [Effective Windows PowerShell](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6930.entry),
  free 50-page eBook by Keith Hill
  (PowerShell MVP)
- Two [Windows PowerShell Workbooks](http://blogs.technet.com/chitpro-de/archive/2008/02/28/free-windows-powershell-workbook-server-administration.aspx)
  including demo files and script
  examples (Introduction to Windows
  PowerShell (44 pages) and
  Administrative tasks with Windows
  PowerShell (78 pages) by Frank Koch
- [PowerShell Day 1](http://www.johndcook.com/powershellbooklet.html), a 10-page
  eBooklet by John D. Cook
- [An Introduction to Microsoft
  PowerShell](http://nexus.realtimepublishers.com/ebmps.php), a 28-page eBooklet by
  Don Jones (PowerShell MVP)

Comment: I have especially enjoyed Mastering Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

[PowerShellCommunity.org](http://www.powershellcommunity.org/) is a portal to all kinds of PowerShell resources.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Scripting Guy http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/sept06/hey0926.mspx

Answer (score 1):

Ars technica has an introductory [article](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2005/10/msh.ars) from when Powershell was still in beta and called Monad. It covers most of the basics and was a good starting point for beginners.

I also found dzone's Powershell [cheat sheet](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/windows-powershell) handy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [www.powershell.com](http://powershell.com/cs/). They have a very good and a comprehensive free e-book called [Master-Powershell](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get started now with a free eBook titled 'Mastering PowerShell'.  The eBook was written by long time Windows PowerShell MVP Dr. Tobias Weltner and can be found on www.powershell.com in HTML or as a downloadable .pdf.

Look for an updated version of Mastering PowerShell on www.PowerShell.com very soon.  The updated eBook will include Windows PowerShell v2 information and will be free to all members of www.powershell.com (membership to the community site is also free).

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth concentrating on Powershell 2.0 as it will be released soon.

The CTP is currently available, more information [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/winpsh/pshell2.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend #powershell on the FreeNode IRC Network.  Several of the MVPs are in regular attendance and questions tend to get quick and excellent answers that include not only how by why.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerScripting Podcast is pretty good; polished and listenable.  I second PowerShell In Action, too.  Great book.

We are starting a Script Club here, too - getting together and scripting with a bunch of other geeks is a great way to bounce ideas around and learn.

The BEST way to learn is to get your hands dirty.  Pick a task and work through it, Googling as necessary.  As new as PowerShell is, there are TONS of great blogs and resources out there.